# Was there ever an effort to reduce the term of the elected members of the Federal Reserve?

Tags: united-states, federal-reserve

> **The seven members of the Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve
> System are nominated by the President and confirmed by the Senate. A
> full term is fourteen years.** One term begins every two years, on
> February 1 of even-numbered years. A member who serves a full term may
> not be reappointed. A member who completes an unexpired portion of a
> term may be reappointed. All terms end on their statutory date
> regardless of the date on which the member is sworn into office.

https://www.federalreserve.gov/aboutthefed/bios/board/default.htm

The fact that elected members can serve 14 years can lead to officials serving beyond the terms of an elected administration. Shorter terms might potentially increase accountability in the sense that Governors would be more directly responsive to the current administration and its economic priorities. This could lead to more immediate responsiveness to changing economic conditions and aligning policies with the goals of the elected government. Was there an effort to reduce the terms for the elected members of the Federal Reserve?

Comment: Part of the rationale of having the federal reserve (and in general, other central banks) is to limit the pressure they might be subjected by politicians towards policies that only are beneficial in the short term.

Comment: To my knowledge, nobody at the Federal Reserve is elected.

Comment: @A.R. To call members of the Federal Reserve who are appointed by the President and confirmed by the U.S. Senate "elected members" of the Federal Reserve is misleading.

Comment: @ohwilleke That was my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Commission on Money and Credit, established in 1957 and which published its report; *[Money and Credit: Their Influence on Jobs, Prices, and Growth](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b3376142)* in 1961, suggested that terms be reduced to 10 years:

> **The FRB should consist of five members, with overlapping ten-year terms, one expiring each odd-numbered year; members should be eligible
> for reappointment.**
>
> This would assure the President of one vacancy to be filled shortly
> after his inauguration while retaining the general stability of Board
> membership. The reduction in numbers should enhance the status of
> members, and the ten-year term combines a sufficient protection for
> independence, with some safeguard against superannuation.
>
> Apart from the instruments of general monetary policy, the Board has
> important regulatory powers over member banks and some other financial
> institutions - for instance in the administration of the Bank Holding
> Company Act and of the anti-trust laws as applied to banks, in the
> approval or disapproval of applications for branches, mergers, and the
> like. These powers are vested in the Board, and the Board appears to
> treat them as non-delegable. Their exercise is exceedingly
> time-consuming and will become considerably more so if the
> Commission's recommendations in Chapter Six regarding the
> consolidation of functions of the Comptroller of the Currency and of
> the FDIC into the FRB are adopted. In this aspect of its work the
> Board has suffered from a malady that has plagued the other
> independent regulatory commissions, a congestion of detailed business
> at the top, to the detriment of the time and energy Board members can
> devote to the broad issues of monetary policy.

This recommendation was not taken up, perhaps for reasons given in a footnote of *[Power and Influence in the Federal Reserve System](https://doi.org/10.2307/2601710)* (Whittlesey 1963):

> With terms starting February 1st as at present, this would enable the
> President to appoint a new Governor soon after taking office, whom he
> could then designate as Chairman. Such an arrangement would clearly
> open the way to political abuse and would make the issue of the
> Chairman's powers doubly significant. A similar result could be
> obtained with the present number of members and length of term of the
> Board simply by moving the terms forward or back so that they would
> expire in odd-numbered years.

This modification continued to be suggested though - the NYT carried [an interview](https://www.nytimes.com/1986/03/23/business/debriefing-a-fed-governor-turning-a-trained-eye-on-a-tense-fed.html) with a retiring member of the board, J. Charles Partlee, in 1986, in which he put the same suggestion forward:

> I would also favor a reduction in the number of board members from
> seven to five.
>
> *Why would you do that?*
>
> The Fed has quite a large
> board, considering that the chairman has both the representational and
> executive-officer functions. Some years ago, we had only five sitting
> members and the board worked well at that size. Also, a member's term is a little too long in today's environment. I
> would not like to upset the general idea of terms staggered every two
> years, but if you had five members, that system would reduce the terms
> of each member from 14 to 10 years.

As far as I can tell from a quick search through proposed legislation, however, this proposal has not yet been put before Congress.